# What's wrong with this bin-to-dec code?

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

Since I have taken a Digital Systems course this semester in Physics school, I decided to try applying what we learn there to my self-taught programming practice. Yeah, we don't do that at all for some reason. Anyway, below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num = 0;
int power = 0; // used to calculate the power of the digit later

vector<int> binVec; // holds binary value
vector<int> decVec; // holds converted dec value

cout << "Input binary number for conversion to its decimal...\n";

while (cin >> num)
{
    binVec.push_back(num);
}


for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i<= binVec.size(); i++)
{
    int temp;

    temp = (binVec[i]*2)^power;
    decVec.push_back(temp);

    if (power = 0)
    {
        power = 2;
    }

    else
    {
        power = power * 2;
    }
}

cout << "The decimal value is \n";

for (vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j<= decVec.size(); j++)
{
    cout << decVec[j];
}

return 0;


 }
```

Needless to say, it won't work correctly. I made some silly mistakes in the beginning, but for about half an hour now that I'm cracking my head with it, I get strange outputs. For example, when I input the simple (10)bin and expect a (2)dec, I get a string of numbers starting with a 2, like 20006721. Also, while the program runs, my compiler sends an error message. What could be wrong?

I know my code sucks and isn't very well optimized, so any feedback or scolding will be much appreciated!

Comment: You should start by posting the error message from the compiler - it'll probably contain something pertinent.

Comment: Your code compiles fine. The error message comes from your program itself or from the operating system. Most likely it is because you access a non-existent index in your vectors. Elements in vectors are numbered 0,1,2,...,size-1. Therfore, you must use "less than" rather than "less or equal" operators in your FOR loops.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on your if statement:

```
if (power = 0)
```

You need to use `==` for comparsions:

```
if (power == 0)
```

Also, in your for loops, your making it run 1 time to many:

```
i <= binVec.size();
```

Arrays are indexed from 0 to size - 1; so doing `<=` makes causes Undefined Behavior for accessing an address outside of the vector's range. Change it to:

```
i < binVec.size();
```

Comment: Classic assignment and equality mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is flawed. For example, you output one decimal digit per binary digit. However, for most binary numbers, the length of the decimal number will be smaller.

In addition, the "^" operator is the binary XOR operator in C++, not the power operator.

Instead of your main loop, I would suggest something like this:

```
int decimalNumber = 0;
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < binVec.size(); i++)
{
    // Note that I changed "less or equal" to "less than"
    decimalNumber *= 2;
    decimalNumber += (binVec[i]);
}
cout << decimalNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version using the accumulate() algorithm from the STL:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Input binary number for conversion to its decimal..." << endl;
    cout << "The decimal value is: " 
         << accumulate(istream_iterator<bool>(cin), istream_iterator<bool>(), 0, 
                       [](int a, int b) { return (a << 1) + b; }) 
         << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of errors have been pointed out.  It has not yet been mentioned that you are doing something rather odd - namely, taking the XOR with the `^` operator. I wonder if you meant to use it as a `power` operation instead?

Here is a suggested conversion - using basic string operations.

```
char* inputString = "101001010";
int ii, dec=0;
for(ii=0; ii<strlen(inputString); ii++) {
  if(*(inputString+ii)=='1') {
    dec = 2 * dec + 1;
  }
  else {
    dec = 2 * dec;
  }
}
printf("the conversion to digital is %d\n", dec);
```

An alternative - using the fact that '0' and '1' are right next to each other in the ASCII table:

```
char* inputString = "101001010";
int ii, dec=0;
for(ii=0; ii<strlen(inputString); ii++) {
  dec = 2 * dec + (int)(inputString[ii]-'0');
}
printf("the conversion to digital is %d\n", dec);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of simple syntax/semantic errors, and a conceptual problem you want to consider.  First, be careful assignment/equality test, you really don't need to start power at zero but 1 (since 2^0 = 1),

Here is part of your code, fixed,

```
int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int bits=0; // you could use bitshift, rather than multiply
    int power=1; // 2^0 = 1, so start power at 1, not 0
```

You loop converts each bit position into a number, but you dont accumulate them,  consider the results of push_back(temp) versus accum+=temp

```
    int temp;
    int accum=0;
    bitpos=0; power=1;
    for (vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<binVec.size(); i++)
    {
        temp = (binVec[i])*power;
        decVec.push_back(temp);
        accum += (binVec[i])<<bitpos;
        bitpos++; power*=2;
    }
```

Since you convert each decimal digit, you have a list of decimal values, but these are not single digits, they are powers of two (2^n) based upon the position in the vector.  You may prefer the value stored in the accum(ulator).  This is clear when you look at the results, printing a comma "," between each vector element,

```
    cout << "The decimal values are ";
    for (vector<int>::size_type j=0; j<decVec.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << decVec[j] << ",";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout << "The decimal value is \n" << accum << endl;
```

Results,

```
./bin2dec
Input binary number for conversion to its decimal: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
The decimal values are 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,0,
The decimal value is 
127
```

This illustrates your last conceptual item, which is that your program considers the leftmost digit least significant, which may be your intention, but counterintutive.  This can be fixed by starting power/bitpos at the rightmost value,

```
    int temp;
    int accum=0;
    //bitpos=0; power=1;
    bitpos=(int)binVec.size()-1; power=2<<bitpos;
    for (vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<binVec.size(); i++)
    {
        temp = (binVec[i])<<bitpos;
        accum += (binVec[i])<<bitpos;
        decVec.push_back(temp);
        //bitpos++; power*=2;
        bitpos--; power/=2;
    }
```

Which gives a more expected result,

```
 ./bin2dec
Input binary number for conversion to its decimal: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
The decimal values are 128,64,32,16,8,4,2,0,
The decimal value is 
254
```